# swiftmailer completely broken for smtp?

Tags: php

Just updated my swiftmailer checkout to the latest version 4.3.0.  The following VERY simple code no longer works, and the connection times out:

```
<? 
require_once 'Swift-4.3.0/lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',465, 'tls')
  ->setUsername('USERNAME')
  ->setPassword('PASSWORD')
  ;
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Yo')
  ->setFrom(array('jnankin@gmail.com' => 'Josh'))
  ->setTo(array('jnankin@gmail.com'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I then get the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Connection to tcp://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465 Timed Out' in /home/jnankin/Desktop/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:169
Stack trace:
#0 /home/jnankin/Desktop/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(400): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->readLine(0)
#1 /home/jnankin/Desktop/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(291): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse(0)
#2 /home/jnankin/Desktop/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(119): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_readGreeting()
#3 /home/jnankin/Desktop/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(80): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#4 /home/jnankin/Desktop/email.php(17): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/jnankin/Desktop/Swift-4.3.0/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 169
```

**UPDATE:** This exact same code (without any changes whatsoever) works in version 4.1.2.  Version 4.1.3 this no longer works.  I've tried different SMTP servers: mailgun, sendgrid, etc... this seems swiftmailer specific.

Comment: Have you tried it with another server?

Answer (score 16):

Looks like starting in version 4.1.3 swiftmailer added starttls support.  In version 4.1.2 and eariler, using port 465 and specifying 'tls' as the encryption method worked fine.  However 4.1.3 looks like it does not support using a tls wrapper and only allows starttls.  In other words "tls" stopped meaning "tls wrapper" and started meaning "starttls".  Thus, changing the port to 587 instead of 465 (as the SES documentation says should be used for starttls connections) solved the problem for me.

Very bad move by swiftmailer imho.